# Having trouble aligining buttons with list bullets - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list and the list items are the buttons like shown in the image.

[Code Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Prateek18/k1gtv6cw)

```css
    .btn {
      overflow: visible;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      background: transparent;
      font: inherit;
      line-height: normal;
      cursor: pointer;
      -moz-user-select: text;
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding: 16px 36px 22px;
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #666;
      border: 2px solid #666;
      border-radius: 6px;
      margin-bottom: 16px;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      border-radius: 15px;
      box-shadow: 5px 7px #999;
    }

    .btn:-moz-focus-inner {
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
    }

    .btn--stripe {
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
    }

    .btn--stripe:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      height: 7px;
      width: 100%;
      background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #666, #666 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 5px);
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      border-top: 1px solid #666;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-size: 7px 7px;
    }

    .btn--stripe:hover {
      background-color: #666;
      color: #fff;
      border-color: #000;
      box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px #888888;
      /*box-shadow:20px 20px 50px grey;  */
    }

    .btn--stripe:hover:after {
      background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #fff, #fff 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 5px);
      border-top: 1px solid #000;
      animation: stripe-slide 12s infinite linear forwards;
    }

    .child-btn {
      font-size: 17px;
      border-radius: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li><button class="btn btn--stripe child-btn" type="submit" name="tt_btn" value="BMS">BMS Room</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn--stripe child-btn" type="submit" name="tt_btn" value="LH310">LH-310</button></li>
</ul>
```

[image]

The buttons are not able to align with the bullets, can anyone help me where I am going wrong?

**Edit**: Problem solved. The problem was in Firefox where I had to remove `display: block;` from my CSS. In Chrome, it works fine.

Comment: Share some code please so that we can tell you exactly what you need. In short you'll have two options, set line-height or remove list style and use a pseudo element. Can give you examples of both if you need it.

Comment: Provide the code.

Comment: I have provided the code. The CSS for button styling is long, should I provide that also?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Prateek Yes please add CSS if that's what you need help with

Comment: Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/Prateek18/k1gtv6cw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is the working snippet for both Chrome & Firefox.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/snt41mwe/1/) to validate.

You just have to remove `display:block;` from the `.btn{...}` class.

```css
.btn {
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 16px 36px 22px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #666;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px 7px #999;
}

.btn:-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.btn--stripe {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.btn--stripe:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #666, #666 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 5px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: 7px 7px;
}

.btn--stripe:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #000;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px #888888;
  /*box-shadow:20px 20px 50px grey;  */
}

.btn--stripe:hover:after {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #fff, #fff 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 5px);
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  animation: stripe-slide 12s infinite linear forwards;
}

.child-btn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li><button class="btn btn--stripe child-btn" type="submit" name="tt_btn" value="BMS">BMS Room</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn--stripe child-btn" type="submit" name="tt_btn" value="LH310">LH-310</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you check for this CSS ?
http://jsfiddle.net/Prateek18/k1gtv6cw

Comment: what is the issue with the fiddle you shared? it looks good to me

Comment: I just saw that the issue is coming when I am using firefox, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have firefox in my office laptop, I can get this fixed and will let you know in the evening.

Comment: @Prateek here is the working snippet both in Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/snt41mwe/1/

Answer (score -1):

```css
#list {
    align-items: left;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.btn {
    width: 20vw;
    border-radius: 20vw;
    height: 15vh;
    margin-top: 2vh;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li><button class="btn btn--stripe child-btn" type="submit" name="tt_btn" value="BMS">BMS Room</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn btn--stripe child-btn" type="submit" name="tt_btn" value="LH310">LH-310</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The same problem is still there

Comment: well then it is a bug in your css..... share us code and we might be of better help

Comment: @Prateek the fiddle looks just fine at my end... whats the issue bro?

Comment: when I use your id="list" css, the buttons are not aligning with the list bullets.

Comment: @Prateek sure they do... what browser are you using?

Comment: I am using mozilla firefox

Comment: @Prateek then there is s.th. in your code which causes the bug on your end which isn't provided here

Comment: I just checked in Chrome and its working fine. But not with firefox, do you have any idea why ?